# Adding columns to Accounting batch (iif & csv)

Tags: accounting, batches

If you have code or an extension that can add columns to the accounting batch export file, please share.

Specifically, we want to add "campaign" and "external id" to every row.

Preferably, we'd like it to update the iif (quickbooks file)

thank you

Comment: if you are using Drupal it would be worth exploring if those options are available to you via a Drupal View

Answer (score 4):

I am not if anyone has done this before but you can use combination of hook_civicrm_batchItems and hook_civicrm_batchQuery to add columns in csv files. I don't think there is any easy solution to add column in iif export file.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I have done this to complete change the layout of the items, works fine :-)